# how to disable compatibility check in excel while automating through c#

Tags: c#, automation, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007 interop assembly to automate Excel through c#. Interop version is 12.0. When I try to save a file, it can be saved only in 2003 format, but thats fine with me, yet I am getting a popup saying compatibility issue. How can I disable this popup?

I have already tried `workbook.CheckCompatibility = false` and  `ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false` so please tell if I am making other mistakes.

I have MS Office 2007 installed on my computer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `ThisWorkBook.DoNotPromptForConvert = true`

More info at [DoNotPromptForConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.donotpromptforconvert.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me. It is still telling me about compatibility issues.

Comment: I found you had to explicitly set all of the following in order to get it work: `ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false` `workbook.CheckCompatibility = false` `workbook.DoNotPromptForConvert = true`

Answer (score 1):

Try instead workbook.CheckCompatibility = false;

Comment: @Keith : CheckCompatibility = false - This worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me. It is still telling me about compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in bold to make it skip the compatibility issue.

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= *filepath or filename* .xls" _
        , **FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled**, CreateBackup:=False