# c# interop.excel no check compatibility on save

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable compatibility check in excel while automating through c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879082/how-to-disable-compatibility-check-in-excel-while-automating-through-c-sharp)

I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
I try to save a XLS with compatibilty 97-2003 using the following code :

```
        private void CreationFichier(_Worksheet template, int nom)
    {
        _Workbook fichierCree = _excel.Workbooks.Add();
        fichierCree.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
        fichierCree.CheckCompatibility = false;

        var feuilleActiveClasseurCree = (_Worksheet)fichierCree.Sheets[1];
        string nomFichier = (nom - 4).ToString() + ".xls";
        label3.Text = "Creation du fichier "+nomFichier+" ...";
        progressBar1.Value++;
        template.Copy(feuilleActiveClasseurCree);

        fichierCree.SaveAs(_folderdestination.SelectedPath + "\\" + nomFichier, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
        fichierCree.Close();
    }
```

But this creates a popup for checking the compatibilty - I don't want this popup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879082/how-to-disable-compatibility-check-in-excel-while-automating-through-c-sharp looks like an exact duplicate

Comment: i add :  fichierCree.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
            fichierCree.CheckCompatibility = false; in my source, but popup appears anyway.

Comment: Source code will be helpful then.

Comment: Silly question but did you add those lines before or after you saved?