# C# interop.excel never check compatibility on save

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`; I try to save a XLS with compatibilty 97-2003 using the following

```
    private void CreationFichier(_Worksheet template, int nom)
    {
        _Workbook fichierCree = _excel.Workbooks.Add();
        fichierCree.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
        fichierCree.CheckCompatibility = false;

        var feuilleActiveClasseurCree = (_Worksheet)fichierCree.Sheets[1];
        string nomFichier = (nom - 4).ToString() + ".xls";
        label3.Text = "Creation du fichier "+nomFichier+" ...";
        progressBar1.Value++;
        template.Copy(feuilleActiveClasseurCree);

        fichierCree.SaveAs(_folderdestination.SelectedPath + "\\" + nomFichier, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
        fichierCree.Close();
    }
```

But this creates a popup for checking the compatibilty - I don't want this popup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zop9.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858072/c-sharp-interop-excel-no-check-compatibility-on-save  is exact duplicate

Comment: Yes but, its close, and no solution was found !*

Comment: did u check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879082/how-to-disable-compatibility-check-in-excel-while-automating-through-c-sharp

Comment: If I recall Interop has fichiereCree.ShowAlerts = False; ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to fix this issue from just code but I did find a solution that works for me. In my case I am opening the same file as a template each time and saving it out as a new file. With Office.Interop.Excel._Application.Visible = true I can see better what is happening. I simply took the master template from my desktop Excel and re-saved it after checking the the don't show this dialog for this box again. Now when I use the file as a template it no longer interrupts my program with the dialog asking about saving for compatibility.

Also, to prevent any file access issues I do a System.IO.File.Copy of the template and then open and save my new file.

This is a late answer and may not solve your specific issue. I hope it is a help to anyone searching for a solution now.